# PHP Regexp help

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to get a handle on what this expression intends to extract:

```
preg_match("/^(?:[\s\*]*?@([^\*\/]+?)\s(.+))/",$line,$match);
```

**$line** is a line from a text file while **$match** is an array

Comment: do you have any idea of what is the content of the $line?

Comment: fireeyedboy got the file text structure right:

/**
 * @class  TestClass
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @package TestTool
 * 
 */

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an explanation:

```
^               # match the beginning of the input
(?:             # start non-capture group 1 
  [\s*]*?       #   match any character from the set {'0x09'..'0x0D', '0x20', '*'} and repeat it zero or more times, reluctantly
  @             #   match the character '@'
  (             #   start capture group 1
    [^*/]+?     #     match any character from the set {'0x00'..')', '+'..'.', '0'..'ÿ'} and repeat it one or more times, reluctantly
  )             #   end capture group 1
  \s            #   match a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
  (             #   start capture group 2
    .+          #     match any character except line breaks and repeat it one or more times
  )             #   end capture group 2
)               # end capture group 1
```

An example string that the regex would match is this: `* * *@abc asd`

**Edit:**

I've released a beta version of the parser that was used to generate the explanation above. It can be downloaded here: http://big-o.nl/apps/pcreparser/pcre/PCREParser.html

Comment: Whoa, do you have a tool to auto-generate that? :-)

Comment: Yes, I wrote a PCRE grammar and used ANTLR to create a PCRE parser/lexer that I used to create such a *regex-explanation*.

Comment: That's absolutely amazing! Do you have this tool available for public use?

Comment: Not yet. I recently finished development, but proper documentation (and unit tests) are running behind, as is almost always the case with my pet projects. If you want, I can send you an e-mail when I *do* make it available (should be within a couple of weeks). If so, drop me a line on my throw-away account `prometheuzz AT gmail DOT com`

Answer (score 2):

Probably tries to capture lines of comment blocks like these (excluding first and last line):

```
/**
 * @param  $arg1 etc...
 * @return bool etc...
 */
```

Comment: This is very much like the source text. What I was wondering is what it's trying to pick in a step by step manner so I can see what it's messing.

Answer (score 0):

This will match strings of the form

```
** *  ***@anything_that_is_not_an_asterisk_nor_a_slash   anything else
```

`$match[1]` contains `"anything_that_is_not_an_asterisk_nor_a_slash"` before the first space, `$match[2]` contains `"  anything else"`.

Comment: This is a good plain English explanation. The code I got the regexp from is actually trying to extract exactly that kind of string, but is messing since it's picking CRLF in $match[2]

Answer (score 0):

the @ make me think the pattern is trying to capture element of an email...
as a ROT always document the regex.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but it matches much, much more. See Kenny's and my answers.

Comment: <id@some.com User Name>, i think the meaning really depends on the input/context, what is the lines look like?